# Django keeps adding "app" to MEDIA_URL in heroku even though DEBUG = True

Tags: python, django, heroku

This is a new error which was never present before when I had the app running on Heroku. However I am now using the Heroku Postgres SQL so that might causing the issue.

Anyways, I have my MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT set as such

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  "portfoliosite", "staticfiles")


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "portfoliosite", "static"),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

THis works fine on my local server. However in production mode, Django keeps adding "app/" to the start of MEDIA_URL.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Here is the 404 error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://www.remosingh.ca/media/images/newlogo_1_TlcOlPh.png
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
“/app/media/images/newlogo_1_TlcOlPh.png” does not exist
```

Comment: What does BASE_DIR resolve to when you print it?